# Using (column-span:all) after (break-after:always) introduces huge gap. Why?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, multiple-columns

When using column-count in a div, if the children are in the following order:

1. text
2. div with break-after:always
3. text
4. text with column-span:all

Then there will be a large gap above the 4th child. Further, this gap seems to shrink as the column-count number increases.

Is there a way of styling elements such that having a div (which spans all columns) after a div (which forces a column break) is possible without introducing this big gap (and not manually placing the elements with position:absolute)?

In this jsfiddle, the first example shows the gap. The second shows how the gap is decreased by increasing the column-count number. The third is roughly what I want it to look like, but can't use any of it's position:absolute nonsense.

<strike>https://jsfiddle.net/1jtogaLg/</strike>

edit: The above example did not convey why the .break element was being used (to force a column break in the case of differing amounts of content). This jsfiddle, however, does demonstrate it: https://jsfiddle.net/1jtogaLg/1/

Which boils down to:

```
<div class="page">
  <p>a</p>
  <div class="break"></div>
  <p>b</p>
  <p class="stretch">Why is this so far down</p>
</div>
<style>
  .page {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #FFF8DC;
    border: 1px solid #E0DCBF;
    margin-right: 5px;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-fill:auto;
  }
  .page * {
    margin:0;
  }  
  .stretch {
    column-span: all;
  }
  .break {
    -webkit-column-break-after: always;
    break-after: always;
  }
</style>
```

Note that the only browser I care about for this is Chrome. If it works in other browsers that's nice, but my target is entirely Chrome.

Comment: Is having that break div there a requirement or can you remove those?  It seems to work the way you want without them, is why I ask, but if you can't then I can pick at it some more.

Comment: Just realized that even if you can't change the structure, making .break display:none ought to do it too

Comment: Thanks for the response. My example didn't make it clear why the break div was in place. It's there to force a column break when the left and right columns should have a different amount of content (which my example did not have). [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1jtogaLg/1/) is an updated jsfiddle which shows why the break div is required.

Comment: That being said, your .break display:none solution absolutely worked for the example as given. But unfortunately my example wasn't specific enough.
I'll update the question to include the newer jsfiddle.

Comment: Messed with it a bit and figured out that you have to apply break-after to the P elements to make it break correctly, but I can't get that spanning element to behave when the height of the .page divs are set https://jsfiddle.net/1jtogaLg/6/